# Failed to get the correct sensor data at firebase using nodemcu esp32. The serial monitor constantly shows zero

Tags: c++, firebase, sensors, heartbeat, arduino-c++

I have been working on the project using the DfRobot heart rate monitor sensor ([wiki_Dfrobot heartrate sensor](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Heart_Rate_Sensor_SKU__SEN0203)) with nodemcu esp 32. I have tested it on the digital mode (code taken from the wiki page with slight modification) and it works perfectly(able to obtain heart beat bpm range from 60-100). However, when i try to use wifi to send the data to firebase, it turns out "0" BPM and "wait for valid data" instead of normal heart beat rate (BPM). Anyone can please help with this problem ?

DFrobot heart rate cpp and h file:
https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_Heartrate

I am using esp32 with Arduino IDE 1.8.12 - using real time firebase

Code(intent to send data to firebase):

```
#define heartratePin 32
#include "DFRobot_Heartrate.h"
#include <WiFi.h>  //1. Include WiFi.h
#include "FirebaseESP32.h"  //2. Include Firebase ESP32 library (this library)



// Set these to run example.
#define FIREBASE_HOST "test.firebaseio.com"  
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "hW8qlM48dGkxxxxxxxx1Pq5UD21YgPq2E0c"
#define WIFI_SSID "Gummya"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "testtest1"

DFRobot_Heartrate heartrate(DIGITAL_MODE); ///< ANALOG_MODE or DIGITAL_MODE
FirebaseData firebaseData;  //3. Declare the Firebase Data object in the global scope



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  initWifi();
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t rateValue;
  heartrate.getValue(heartratePin); ///< A1 foot sampled values
  rateValue = heartrate.getRate(); ///< Get heart rate value
    if(Firebase.setInt(firebaseData,"HeartBeat/BPM_data", rateValue)){
    //if (firebaseData.dataType()== "Int")
    Serial.println(rateValue);
  }

  delay(20);
}

 void initWifi(){
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();

  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
  
  //Set database read timeout to 1 minute (max 15 minutes)
  Firebase.setReadTimeout(firebaseData, 1000 * 60);
  //tiny, small, medium, large and unlimited.
  //Size and its write timeout e.g. tiny (1s), small (10s), medium (30s) and large (60s).
  Firebase.setwriteSizeLimit(firebaseData, "tiny");
 }
```

Serial Monitor output:

[image: Serial Monitor shows 0 BPM]

Got the FirebaseESP32.h library from -->  https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP32

I've searched for quite awhile but ended up with nothing, Im fairly new to arduino and programming so please help me.  I will be grateful to you.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: It seems that you're not getting any values from your sensor. In fact, you should be able to reproduce the problem without any code related to Firebase. I'd recommend doing that and reducing the code in your question. The less code, the more likely a person with the right knowledge to help will see what is going wrong. For more hints on that, also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, I have managed to get the value when I just work on the code provided on the wikipage (with slight modification). That was without the wifi connecting to firebase. I would like to apologize if my question/issue stated here is unclear and confusing. Are u suggesting me to make my code shorter and not to mention firebase? I wasn't sure if I got what u mean